# On eclipse C++ code style single line format

Tags: c++, eclipse, formatting, accessor, modifier

I have a problem with eclipse's code style, here is the problem:

when I write an accessor or a modifier in C++ code, for example:

```
string GetName() { return name; }
```

then I press ctrl+shift+f and this line becomes:

```
string GetName() {
    return name;
}
```

But I just want it to stay the way like:

```
string GetName() { return name; }
```

How can I configure that? In other words how can I configure so one line code can stay in one line after I press `ctrl+shift+f`?

Expand the situation, how can I configure that in case of Java with eclipse?

Thank you!

Sincerely,

Comment: Which version of CDT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that in control statements (in the code formatting options, go to the `"Control Statements"` tab, `"if else"` section, and choose `"keep simple if in one line"`), but I don't think you can do that for functions.